# When calling "number".ToString("C", new CultureInfo("es-uy")), I get different result on server

Tags: c#, decimal, currency, tostring, cultureinfo

When running a service on my machine (using .net framework or .net Core 1.1 or .net core 3) and call *toString* method to get some value on Uruguay currency, I get it **the way I want**:

```
var number = 321456m;
Console.WriteLine(number.ToString("C", new CultureInfo("es-UY"));
```

**Output:** $ 321.456,00 - Correct

When running on production server, the output for the same code is different, can call it wrong:

**Output on server:** $U 321.456,00

Somebody knows the reason for that? How can I set the server output the same of localhost?

I checked and tested a lot of scenarios with **CultureInfo** but the only attribute I couldn't set like the server is **InstalledUICulture** (mine is **pt-br** and the server is **en-us**)

Comment: What is the Currency Symbol set to on your production server? (Under Region Settings -> Additional Settings -> Currency tab)

Comment: @MatthewWatson it's set to "$" and the location "United States".

I tried somethings like


`CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("es-UY");
CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("es-UY");`

but with no success

Comment: You need to check what it's set to for Uruguay, the U.S. English is just the default. You're setting the thread locale to Uruguay so it'll use that setting.

Comment: The fact: Uruguay currency symbol is "$". The other symbol ($U) is also from Uruguay currency, but is not used. The question is, why even setting the same culture on ToString I get different values for currency symbol?